# Commands like 1; and 2c1; on shell

Tags: c, shell

I am developing a simple "tar-like" archiving C program. It works by writing all files, directories and file contents in a text file, and it can extract them in the same way (it creates empty files, and then fill them with archive content).

When I have to archive text files or PDFs, it works well.

With audio files such as MP3s, at the end of extraction, i have these lines on shell:

```
1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;
2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;
2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c;1;1;112;112;
1;0x1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c;1;1;112;112;1;0x1;2c1;2c1;2c1;
2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;
2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c
```

I don't know why program writes this on shell, and why it does like this only with audio tracks. By executing them, I noticed that only `1;`commands are executed, and `2c1;`commands are unknown.

Can you help me find out why?

This is code i wrote for extracting part:

```
void crea_file(FILE *f)                                             // crea i file estratti dall'archivio
{
    int contatore = 0;
    char x[4096];
    bool listTrovata = false;
    while (fscanf(f, " %s", x) == 1) {
        if(strcmp(x, "%LIST%")==0 && listTrovata==false)
        {
            listTrovata= true;
            puts("trovato il primo \n");
            continue;
        }
        else if (strcmp(x, "%LIST%")==0 && listTrovata)
        {
            long position;
            position = ftell(f);
            printf("trovato il secondo \n");
            printf("LIST trovato alla posizione %ld", position);
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
            break;
        }
        else if (listTrovata)
        {
            contatore++;
            char* file;                         // stringa contenente il percorso da aprire (verrà creato in seguito)
            file = collega(getcwd(NULL, 0), x);
            creat(file, PERMS);
            printf("sto cercando l'inizio e la fine di content, passando un contatore %d \n", contatore);
            trovaInizioFine(contatore);
            printf("ora scrivo il file trovato");
            scriviFile(file);
            //inserisco funzione che parte da inizio e scrive carattere per carattere nel file destinazione. se la posizione di ftell è uguale a fine, allora esci.
        }
    }
    printf("esco \n");
}

void trovaInizioFine(int cont)                                      // trova il carattere di inizio e di fine del file nella sezione %CONTENT%
{
    FILE* contenuto;
    char * path;
    char x[4096];
    int i =1;
    path = collegaSlash(getcwd(NULL, 0), nome);

    contenuto = fopen(path, "r");
    while (fscanf(contenuto, "%s", x) == 1) 
    {
        if(strcmp(x, "%CONTENT%")==0 && i == ((cont*2)-1) )
        {
            inizio = ftell(contenuto);
            puts("trovato il primo \n");
            //puts(x);
            printf("CONTENT trovato alla posizione %d \n", inizio);
            i++;
        }
        else if(strcmp(x, "%CONTENT%")==0 && i == ((cont*2)) )
        {
            fine = ftell(contenuto);
            daleggere = fine-9;
            puts("trovato il primo \n");
            printf("CONTENT trovato alla posizione %d \n", fine);
            break;
            i++;
        }
        else if(strcmp(x, "%CONTENT%")==0)
        {
            i++;    
        }


        printf("giro numero %d \n", i);
    }

    printf("esco da trova Inizio File  \n");
    fclose(contenuto);

}

void scriviFile(const char * arrivo)                                //scrive i file creati in precedenza
{
    FILE * partenza;
    FILE * target;
    int c;
    int spazio = 'a';
    int i = 0;
    int pos;
    char * path;
    path = collegaSlash(getcwd(NULL, 0), nome);
    partenza = fopen(path, "r");
    fseek(partenza, inizio, SEEK_SET);
    target = fopen(arrivo, "w");                                            //apro il file
    if (target) {                                                               //se è aperto
        while ((c = fgetc(partenza)) != EOF && ftell(partenza)<=fine-10) {                                  //e il carattere preso non eccede la fine del file
            fputc(c, target);
            fputc(c, stdout);
            pos = ftell(partenza);
            if(pos==fine)
            {
                break;
            }
                                                                            //scrivo lo stesso carattere in out (file in uscita)
        }                                                                   //

        fclose(target);                                                     //chiudo il file
        fclose(partenza);
    } 
    else 
    {
        printf("errore di scrittura del file \n");
    }

}
```

my archive has 3 section: %LIST%, %DIRS% and %CONTENT%.

`crea_file` reads %LIST% section and creates empty files in current directory. 
`TrovaInizioFine` reads %CONTENT% section and saves 2 indexes: one at beginning of file content, and one at its end. 
`scrivifile` fills empty file with archive content.

Comment: Without any code, you realize this is quite hard to help with, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any code to look at, this is quite hard.

Still, one thing you say makes me suspect problems:

> It works by writing all files, directories and file contents in a text file

You can't treat arbitrary binary data as text, in most cases. The C libraries might to end-of-line translation, which will destroy binary data. You must use *binary* files for arbitrary data, or take care to "protect" the data so that it really survives being treated as text.

Go binary.

Comment: I changed my program: now works even on binaries. It extracts photos correctly, but these lines remain..